# need batch files script for Copy files from one directory into multiple directories

Tags: command-line

in our regular work we have 500 to 600 hundred voice files we need to distribute in user so we are doing copy past one one files manually we have list of files copy source and destination. now we need batch files for do our work easy.any can help me..?

batch files script  for Copy files from one directory in multiple directories

Comment: What batch language and OS?

Comment: what does "distribute in user" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to get you started. For each entry in a list of files, copy that file somewhere else (in MSDOS batch scripting):

```
SET DEST=C:\foo
REM Create list of resources to build
SET FILELIST=tmp
ECHO File1.doc > %FILELIST%
ECHO File2.doc >> %FILELIST%
ECHO File3.doc >> %FILELIST%

REM Copy each file
for /F "tokens=1" %%F in (%FILELIST%) do (
  ECHO + Copying %%F
  copy /Y "%%F" %DEST%
)
DEL /F %FILELIST% > nul
```

Hope that helps :)

Perhaps you may want to read more [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/).